# How to bypass the M_PI error without affecting the code while compiling the Castro library?

Tags: c++, gnu-make

I installed the [Castro library](https://github.com/AMReX-Astro/Castro) for astronomical modelling, and I followed the build setup described [here](https://amrex-astro.github.io/Castro/docs/getting_started.html). I successfully changed the parameters in GNUmakefile (as described in the tutorial), but when I ran the command `make` in `....Castro/Exec/hydro_tests/Sedov` directory, I got several errors, the majority of them being `'M_PI' was not declared in this scope`. I googled about the error, and the majority of the answers were referring to building of own code (one file, or so). The main reason was clear: I am using MS stuff (I am running Windows, with installed g++ and VS compiler) and `M_PI` is not supported by default. Instead, I should define `_USE_MATH_DEFINES`.

The problem is that I want to have a convenient solution: I don't want to search for every instance of `M_PI` and replace it, or add to every file `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES`. Instead, I want to alter the `make` command so that `_USE_MATH_DEFINES` is defined in every file. Unfortunately, I haven't yet used `make` much, so I don't know how to do this.

The `GNUmakefile` (which is the only `make`-related file) doesn't help much:

```
PRECISION  = DOUBLE
PROFILE    = FALSE

DEBUG      = FALSE

DIM        = 2

COMP       = gnu

USE_MPI    = FALSE
USE_OMP    = FALSE

USE_MHD    = FALSE

USE_FORT_MICROPHYSICS := FALSE
BL_NO_FORT := TRUE

# define the location of the CASTRO top directory
CASTRO_HOME  := ../../..

# This sets the EOS directory in $(MICROPHYSICS_HOME)/EOS
EOS_DIR     := gamma_law

# This sets the network directory in $(MICROPHYSICS_HOME)/Networks
NETWORK_DIR := general_null
NETWORK_INPUTS = gammalaw.net

Bpack   := ./Make.package
Blocs   := .

include $(CASTRO_HOME)/Exec/Make.Castro
```

I, therefore, ask you to give the correct `make` command, or give any other option of bypassing the error.

Comment: Since you haven't shown us a makefile, or even disclosed what language the code you're compiling is written in (presumably either C or C++, due to `#define`) it's hard to say, but most likely you should look through your makefile for a variable like `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS` and add the flag `-D__USE_MATH_DEFINES` to the value of that variable.  Then when you run `make` you should look at the compiler commands that are run and make sure that flag appears on them.  If not, then you didn't modify the right variable.

Comment: @MadScientist What if there are no ```CXXFLAGS```? The ```GNUmakefile``` seems to me a rather strange makefile.

Comment: Well, it says `include $(CASTRO_HOME)/Exec/Make.Castro` so I recommend you look there.

Comment: There's no way to provide a make command that does what you want without understanding the environment.  Everything in make is controlled through variables, and there are no hardcoded variable names that everyone must use: there are only recommended standard variables.  Makefile authors can write their own rules and use whatever variables they like.

Comment: @MadScientist Nope, nothing here as well.

Comment: Well, there are still more `include` lines in _that_ included file, that will have to be examined.  You'll just have to keep investigating if you want to find the root of the build.  But, the answer below is probably good enough (adding a value to the `DEFINES` make variable).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: as @MadScientist points out, the position of `DEFINES=` in the commandline matters:

- `make DEPENDS=...` is an [overriding variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding) which ignores extensions
- `DEPENDS=... make` sets a [value from the environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Environment) which is fine.

I originally had the first form, which is wrong.

It looks like that system extends preprocessor defines set in the `DEFINES` variable, so the following should work:

```
DEFINES=-D__USE_MATH_DEFINES make
```

If you don't want to type that everytime, you can do

```
export DEFINES=-D__USE_MATH_DEFINES
```

once and then call
`make` several times.

Comment: ```error: argument --defines: expected one argument```

Comment: You absolutely cannot use the first suggestion here: overriding `DEFINES` on the make command line will almost certainly cause havoc because it throws away all the values of that variable defined anywhere in the makefiles and replaces it with just that one value.  It's not clear what's being suggested in the second option: if what's being suggested is to add that to your shell setup it may work, if the makefiles are written carefully.  Better is probably to add `DEFINES += -D__USE_MATH_DEFINES` into your `GNUmakefile`.

Comment: As for your error message, you'll have to do better than that if you need help.  There is nothing in the suggestion that references `--defines` so there's no way we can know what  is going on there.  You need to show the command line that make invoked, that caused that error, along with the complete error message including all context.  Please use cut and paste and edit your question to add it there so it can be properly formatted, unlike in comments.